# Color white and black, black should be at first

Tags: html, css

```
.color {color:#000; background-color:#fff; color:#fff}

<p class="color">some text</p>
```

The result as below:(nothing) My question here why should color in `#000` ignored?!!!!

Comment: In CSS the last declaration is the one the gets applied. Read the documentation about Cascading and Specificity: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/450/cascading-and-specificity#t=201607311724118951523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS, compiler overrides any rules found last with all the previous ones, unless you add `!important` in your styles.